# Facebook - Getting status updates from Page (not user) using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is there a way of getting status updates from a Page (not from a users page , but a business page) using FQL , documentation for the 'page' table doesn't contain anything ?

So my query would theoretically be:

```
SELECT status FROM page WHERE page_id = MYPAGEID
```

although that obviously doesn;t work , and :

```
SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = MYPAGEID
```

just returns NULL.

The page is public , and all security permissions are off .

Any ideas? I can't see any reason as to why Facebook wouldn't allow this ?

Ive used

```
https://graph.facebook.com/MYPAGEID/feed
```

but ideally I'd like to return XML to integrate it into a feed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to query the [`stream`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table:

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id=PAGE_ID
```

OR:

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id=PAGE_ID AND actor_id=PAGE_ID
```

If you only want to retrieve the feeds **made** by the page!

Comment: Thanks for the response, this still does not produce results for a Page, it does produce results for a User though.

Comment: @BobFlemming: Are you sure about your page id? it's working for me and also for the [coca-cola](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id=40796308305) page

Comment: Hmmmm... most posts on my page are linked in from Twitterfeed app. I can only assume this is the reason its not showing up. Thanks for the help